# How can i separate var's labels in "plot.psych", library(psych)

Tags: r, plot, label, psych

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfStO.png)

Psych is R package. I'm finding an option similar to "repel", for "psych".The names of the variables appear superimposed so it is difficult to read them in the graph, I need to introduce an option in the plot code.